# Can my warlock use the Actor feat to mimic speech through my familiar using the Voice of the Chain Master eldritch invocation?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, warlock, familiars, eldritch-invocations

The [Actor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/actor) feat states (PHB, p. 165):

> You can mimic the speech of another person or the sounds made
> by other creatures. You must have heard the person speaking, or heard
> the creature make the sound, for at least 1 minute. A successful
> Wisdom (Insight) check contested by your Charisma (Deception) check
> allows a listener to determine that the effect is faked.

The [Voice of the Chain Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#VoiceoftheChainMaster) eldritch invocation for warlocks states (emphasis mine):

> You can communicate telepathically with your familiar and perceive
> through your familiar’s senses as long as you are on the same plane of
> existence. Additionally, while perceiving through your familiar’s
> senses, *you can also speak through your familiar **in your own
> voice**, even if your familiar is normally incapable of speech*.

In a nutshell: **Can I make my familiar imitate someone else's voice in a way that might fool them?**

Basically, I'm hoping for some fun ways to sow discord, confusion, and otherwise mess (or even parley) with my enemies, all from the safety of a distant enough location on the same plane of existence.

Similar questions have been asked here, but they all centered around the ability to [cast spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64608/does-the-voice-of-the-chain-master-eldritch-invocation-let-me-cast-a-purely-verb), or use [spell-like abilities](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/176326/can-you-use-the-diplomat-feat-through-your-familiar-with-the-voice-of-the-chain) (you can't).

My gut says that while technically it's not my characters' voice *per se*, it is my character's voice imitating someone else's in a mundane (non-magical) way, so it should function properly.

Is there an official rule or ruling on whether this works?

Comment: Not an answer, but the Actor feat is very unpopular, as well as the the Pact of the Chain 
 feature. Both are considered inferior comparing to their counterparts. So as a DM I'd definitely allow synergy between them, regardless of the RAW.

Comment: I agree with the popularity part. This seems odd to me because it also stacks really well with the "Mask of many faces" Eldritch invocation. Sure you can look like a henchman or boss, but can you sound like them?

Comment: A relevant question: [Can anyone mimic a sound or speech and what do they roll?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101948/)

Comment: While these 2 may be unpopular among optimizers, I think actor is used often enough, and VotCM is used for the telepathy part, which makes scouting trivial.

Comment: I think the reason it isn't picked much is precisely because of the linked question, who picks a feat that simply saves them time? Generally I rule that if a feat lets you do something, then you can't do it without the feat, or at least not very well, so if it becomes important to your character concept you lean into it and pick the feat!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You're speaking in your own voice, so you can mimic speech.

There's no strict ruling regarding this, but the rules you mention specify that you're speaking using your own voice, so it stands to reason that you can mimic others using the Actor feat. As it is your own voice, the listener could still attempt the opposed Wisdom (Insight) check against your Charisma (Deception) check, even though it's technically your familiar making the noise.

The same thing would apply to spells like [Animal Messenger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animal-messenger) or [Magic Mouth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-mouth) that play back the sound of your voice--you're doing the mimicry when you create the message, and thus the Actor feat applies.